# Porting Windows 8 Metro app to Windows 10 Universal app

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-10, win-universal-app

I currently have a windows 8 metro app built around 12 months ago. It currently runs on a touch screen but we want to port it to universal apps so we can use it on a tablet or pc. Is this currently possible without a large amount of code/scaffolding changes?

Comment: It should be straightforward. See Move from Windows Runtime 8.x to UWP at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt238322.aspx .

Comment: As your app will be probably .NET Native, I would advise to read also [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600634(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your app should run without changes on Windows 10. To take full advantage of the new features like cortana and switch between tablet&desktop mode you should think about upgrading your app to uwp.